# JavaScript: Create instance of type X, based on prototype member

Tags: javascript

I have the prototypes `x`, `y`, and `z`. I want to initialize an instance `n` in prototype `i` with the type of either `x`, `y`, or `z` based on a member of `i`. Can this be done?

For illustration purposes

```
function X(value) {
    this.value = value
}

X.prototype.add(v) {
  this.value ^ v;
}

function Y(value) {
    this.value = value
}

Y.prototype.add(v) {
  this.value << v;
}

function Z(value) {
    this.value = value
}

Z.prototype.add(v) {
  this.value * v;
}

function I(field) {
    this.field = field;
    this.fields = [];
}

I.prototype.createField(value) {
   fields.push(new this.field(value));
}

I.prototype.sumOfField() {
   var res = 0;
   fields.forEach(function (element){element.add(res)});
}

var temp = new I(Y);
```

Comment: You want `res` to be the type of what is inside fields ?
Beside, your `add` methods don't actually change values.

Comment: Is the `createField` function where your problem is?

Comment: you're missing `this` before `fields.push` and `fields.forEach` and your `add()` methods don't do anything. They compute a value and discard it immediately, without returning or changing any state. They don't do as little as even log the computed value.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does work, as I fixed some syntax errors :

- `Z.prototype.add(v) {` becomes `Z.prototype.add = function(v) {`.
- `this.value * v` doesn't do anything on its own, I assumed you wanted 
  to change value field so I changed it to this : `this.value *=v`.
- Finally, you forgot `this` before each calls to `fields` (`forEach` and 
  `push`).

```js
function Z(value) {
  this.value = value;
}

Z.prototype.add = function(v) {
  this.value *= v;
}

function I(field) {
  this.field = field;
  this.fields = [];
}

I.prototype.createField = function(value) {
  this.fields.push(new this.field(value));
}

I.prototype.sumOfField = function() {
  var res = 2;
  this.fields.forEach(function(element) {
    element.add(res);
  });
}

var temp = new I(Z);

for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  temp.createField(i);
}

temp.sumOfField();

console.log(temp.fields);
```